# Showing Excel Documents on the Web

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, excel

I'm looking for a way to present excel documents on the web either by :

converting Excel documents to html, css and javascript or by,
using silverlight control

I'm not looking for a way to program the conversion by my self. What I'm after is a control or library (open source or third - party ) which will enable me to present excel file inside a web browser.

SOLUTION:
We've found two solutions to this problem both which work and are free:
1. PHPExcell is an excellent third party library for reading and creating excel files. For our project we have created a PHP Rest service to which our .NET application sends the data which needs to be converted to excell and the resulting file is just sent then to the client.
2. For the second solution we have installed Open office and started it in its headless mode. We used its UNO CLI API to create an utility API in .NET for any conversion possible in Openoffice (e.g. Excell to PDF to Word etc., Convert(File, From: Format.Excell, To: Format.PDF) ). We used the Java tutorials on the web for this since the syntax is very similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can try SQL Server Reporting Services with the help of some third party software like [OfficeWriter](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/OfficeWriter-250.aspx).

**Edit:** SSRS is free with SQL Server 2005 Express

Comment: Fair play - I haven't really played with the express editions :)

Answer (score 2):

[SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com) is a great development platform that allows you to manipulate and generate Excel files with managed code, no install of Excel required.  You can do things like convert a datatable to a spreadsheet, execute macros in a spreadsheet from code, etc.
You could convert your spreadsheet to a datatable and simply display it in a datagrid.

Comment: SpreadsheetGear can also convert charts and ranges of cells to gifs or pngs or jpegs. See the live web samples at http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/. Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: We missed - I just told one of my developers and he's geeked to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FlexCel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Excel Services in MOSS 2007](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/DisplayingCharts.aspx) (SharePoint)